# Unsubscribed app is still active!

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

I've cancelled a subscription in my iphone but it is still showing in my subscription list! Apple says "If you don’t see Cancel Subscription, the subscription is already canceled and won't renew.", so why should it be shown 'active'? I'm afraid it's not canceled.

How can I remove it totally? I have even removed the app. what should I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039):

> Tap Cancel Subscription. If you don’t see Cancel Subscription, the subscription is already canceled and won't renew.

You stated you don't see the Cancel Subscription button so that means it's already canceled. Cancelling means that it won’t renew now at the next interval. If you want to be very safe to double check, you could reinstall the app and delete it when connected to the internet. Apple will ask if you want to cancel the subscription when you delete an app with an active subscription.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039

Comment: My problem is that it is still shown active in the subscription list.

Comment: @FatemehAsgarinejad Please post a screenshot to you question.  You will still see the subscription in the lost, even if canceled.

Comment: @FatemehAsgarinejad subscriptions are valid until their next renewal date, at which point if they are cancelled they wont renew.  If you take out an annual subscription and cancel it on the first day, you get another 364 days of its benefits and then nothing.